# VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack dropwizard

Tags: intellij-idea, microservices, dropwizard, java-11

We upgraded the java version to 11 in a microservice.
When we tried to run the app, we got the following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/template/main/App.initialize(Lio/dropwizard/setup/Bootstrap;)V @153: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor' (current frame, stack[4]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @153
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/template/main/App', 'io/dropwizard/setup/Bootstrap', 'com/bendb/dropwizard/jooq/JooqBundle' }
    stack: { 'io/dropwizard/setup/Bootstrap', uninitialized 137, uninitialized 137, 'io/dropwizard/configuration/ConfigurationSourceProvider', 'io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b b700 052a b600 064d 2b2c b600 072b
    0000010: bb00 0859 b700 09b6 0007 2bbb 000a 59b7
    0000020: 000b b600 0c2a b800 0d12 0eb6 000f bb00
    0000030: 1059 b700 11b6 0012 bb00 1359 2cb7 0014
    0000040: b600 12bb 0015 59b7 0016 b600 12bb 0017
    0000050: 59b7 0018 b600 12bb 0019 59b7 001a b600
    0000060: 12bb 001b 59b7 001c b600 1204 bd00 1d59
    0000070: 0312 1e53 b600 1fb2 0020 b600 21b5 0022
    0000080: 2b2a b400 22b6 0007 2bbb 0023 592b b600
    0000090: 24bb 0025 5903 b700 26b7 0027 b600 282b
    00000a0: bb00 2959 2ab7 002a b600 0c2b bb00 2b59
    00000b0: 2ab7 002c b600 07b1
```

Any idea how can we fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/issues/283

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027974